# Jquery notification (onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I have a page which has sticky notifications on it, these only work when clicked on, is there a way to show these when the page loads?

```
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " id="gritter-regular">Regular</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: The Javascript is 388 lines long and im not sure which bit i need to show you??

Comment: your code not the library

Comment: @AbstractChaos sorry, new to this what does that mean?

Comment: you have written some code between `<script>` tags that uses the gritter.js, the code to show is between the `<script>`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this after the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.gritter.add({
          title: 'Sticky notice',
          text: 'will not disappear until closed',
          sticky: true
      });
    });
</script>
```

opens up a notice once the document is ready and set to not close by itself